# Why can't java find my fonts?

Tags: 14.04, python, java, fonts, pycharm

Whenever I try to run any jar file via `java -jar file.jar`, I get an exception saying:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: fontFile`

I just earlier today was having the same issue with PyCharm when trying to make some plots with `pyplot`. I fixed that by simply reinstalling anaconda. And I could reinstall java, I suppose, but there must be a simple fix. How can I make java look in the right place for fonts, since I assume that's what the problem is.

Other applications like LibreOffice can use all fonts just fine.

Comment: This may be a long shot but try `sudo fc-cache -fv` to rebuild your font cache.

Comment: @edwinksl I appreciate your help, but I ended up doing exactly what I said I didnt want to and reinstalled java, everything is working. Though I learned nothing